# How to programmatically switch to ReteOO algorithm in drools 6.3.0?

Tags: java-8, drools

I am working on a project that involves Java 8 and Drools 6.3.0. Earlier I used to work with Java 7 and Drools 5.4.0 . I have learned that after Drools 6.0.0 PHREAK has been set as the default algorithm. While googling for the issue i came across some solution that suggested passing the arguments **-Ddrools.ruleEngine=reteoo** to explictly set it. When I did the same i came across the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cmn.rules.canonical.CanRuleEngineFactory$CanRuleEngineFactoryWrapper
at cmn.rules.canonical.CanRuleEngineFactory.getInstance(CanRuleEngineFactory.java:33)
at cmn.service.impl.SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.applyLoaderRules(SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.java:69)
at cmn.service.impl.SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.load(SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.java:216)
at udl.persistence.LoaderDelegatorImpl.load(LoaderDelegatorImpl.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.load(Unknown Source)
at udl.core.task.LoaderTask.executeTask(LoaderTask.java:139)
at cmn.core.concurrent.WorkerThread.runTask(WorkerThread.java:94)
at cmn.core.concurrent.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:74)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, when i pass the argument **-Ddrools.ruleEngine=phreak** , the code works without any issues.

Another suggestion was something as below,
My code is something like this

```
private static KnowledgeBaseConfiguration kBaseConf;
kBaseConf = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
kBaseConf.setProperty("drools.ruleEngine", "reteoo");
KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(kBaseConf);
kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
return kbase;
```

This resulted in the following error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseFactoryServiceImpl.java:75)
    at org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseFactory.java:88)
    at RuleEngineFactory.readKnowledgeBase(RuleEngineFactory.java:139)
    at RuleEngineFactory.createRuleFromResource(RuleEngineFactory.java:104)
    at RuleEngineFactory.<init>(RuleEngineFactory.java:79)
    at canonical.AbstractCanonicalRuleEngineFactory.<init>(AbstractCanonicalRuleEngineFactory.java:40)
    at canonical.CanRuleEngineFactory.<init>(CanRuleEngineFactory.java:31)
    at canonical.CanRuleEngineFactory.getInstance(CanRuleEngineFactory.java:38)
    at PersistanceServiceImpl.applyLoaderRules(SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.java:69)
    at PersistanceServiceImpl.load(SecurityPersistanceServiceImpl.java:218)
    at com.dclear.udl.persistence.LoaderDelegatorImpl.load(LoaderDelegatorImpl.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.load(Unknown Source)
```

I will be much oblidged if someone can provide a solution or atleast some pointer for the issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can "successfully" set the KieBase configuration option using  KieBaseConfiguration and the non-stable (!)   RuleEngineOption from the package org.kie.internal.builder.conf.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieBaseConfiguration kbConf = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
kbConf.setOption( RuleEngineOption.RETEOO );
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase( kbConf );
```

It is also possible to produce the setting using -Ddrools.ruleEngine=reteoo on the command line for starting the Java application.

You can verify that the option setting is successful using

```
System.out.println( kbConf.getProperty( "drools.ruleEngine" ) );
```

After the "successful" setting, and when executing

```
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase( kbConf );
```

the program runs but notifies you

```
[main] WARN org.drools.core.RuleBaseConfiguration - 
       Cannot find drools-reteoo.jar on the classpath, 
       switching to phreak
```

But this jar isn't contained in the 6.2.0 distribution. I think that the switch  was just a temporary hack to switch back during 6.0.0 development.

Stay with 5.4.0 (or 5.5.0 or later) and use Java 8 - there shouldn't be a problem. Or stay with PHREAK - it is supposed to be better.

Comment: We are using Knowledge API not the Kie API. Can you please provide the same solution using Knowledge API ?

Comment: Also do you have any information regarding the -**Ddrools.ruleEngine=reteoo** ?

Comment: The Knowledge API is deprecated in 6.x. But you can look up these calls in the javadoc.

Comment: drools-reteoo is now part of the distribution again, as of 6.3. It was always on nexus distribution.